# Jenkins: How do I checkout a specific commit SHA1 in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm facing a problem in my Jenkinsfile that seemed to be straightforward to me but is actually a real puzzle.
My need is simple : I want to checkout a Git repository but with a specific commit, using its SHA1, which is a parameter of my job. I know it was possible with Jenkins Job builder configuration in the Git SCM section, and I want to reproduce the same behaviour.

Here's my code :

```
pipeline {
   agent {
      label 'test'
   }
   stages {
      stage('Checkout') {
         steps {
            checkout([
               $class: 'GitSCM',
               branches: [
                  [name: params.COMMIT_SHA1]
               ],
               extensions: [
                  [
                     $class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
                     relativeTargetDir: 'foo'
                  ]
               ],
               userRemoteConfigs: [
                  [
                     credentialsId: 'credentials-id',
                     url: 'ssh://path/to/repo'
                  ]
               ]
            ])
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This checkout fails.

- I'm sure the SHA1 exists
- The GitSCM class documentation is clear about the fact that a commit ID can be used as branch name

I've already tried with and without quotes, or a `def commitSHA1 = params.COMMIT_SHA1` in a script{} section, but it didn't solve my problem.
Do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance